# How to use a Server to run OnlyOwner functions?

Tags: server-side, reward, access, games

I'm working on a game PoC and I've got questions about player rewards good practices.

Sure I understand that those functions cannot be public and onlyOwner-restricted, but how does it work actually ?

I'm thinking about running a server that would handle players reward queries and "relay" those claim and reward functions through the Owner account if the calls are valid. But I can't find any resources about this. I suppose the server needs to have access to the network through its own Metamask account ??

Any pointers would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can store owner's private key and run scripts to call only-owner functions regularly. Please be sure those functions do not cost too much gas. To avoid gas over-consumption, you need to be careful and loops, storage variables and so on. You can find more details [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/solidity-gas-optimizations-and-tricks-2bcee0f9f1f2?gi=76d785f048e9)